# how to preprocess dataset with dplyr and sqlite

Tags: r, sqlite, simulation, dplyr

I am running a simulation using R on a HP-Cluster.
The output is saved via the `saveRDS()` function. The file, once extracted, is too big to process it directly in R.
If I would be able to do one "preprocessing step" outside R, this would drastically decrease the size of the dataset.
The step is simply taking the mean of a value with respect to a factor (`group_by()` and `summarise()` in dplyr). 
I came across  [this](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) page. Unfortunately, it is only described how to copy an already loaded dataframe to sqlite. Is there a simple way to copy an external file (RDS) to sqlite without having to first read it in R? Because that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried saving it as csv file with `write.table` instead of `saveRDS`? As you can easily load the csv file into an sqlite database using the shell?

Comment: The output must have fit in some R in order to create the rds file - if you can fit it in memory, that will be much faster to use dplyr on it there rather than going via sqlite.

Comment: thanks. I am using the simsalapar package for my simulation. However, I might be able to rewrite the relevant function to achieve this.